# What companies and institutions accept ADA as payment?

Tags: ada

It would be good to have a central database of all known merchants that accept ADA for transactions.

I've seen a few small businesses posted on r/Cardano that I went 'good for them', and made me wonder of a place where you could check for people and businesses accepting ADA as a method of payment.

Note: IIRC, Shopify allows for ADA payments, not natively, but through an app in Shopify's marketplace.

Comment: This shouldn't be posted as a question here, Stack Exchange is not a place to make proposals, but a place to resolve doubts, and what you want is not an answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answers will be changing every few days

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not know of such a list, but it would be very cool if someone started such a list within a repository, similar to [essential Cardano](https://github.com/input-output-hk/essential-cardano/blob/main/essential-cardano-list.md).

Comment: That's a good one, didn't know about it, thanks.